# multiple if conditions in matlab

Tags: matlab

while running the code below, the conditions (1) and (3) are not read in Matlab. 
     I tried my best but couldn't figure the mistake. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 % inputs are a_s, p, t, a
 % a_s=single number
 % p,t,a are column vectors
 % output is P (also a column vector)

 if a_s<a<=a_s-180
     if p<=180-t    %------(1)
         P=p+t;
     elseif p>180-t %------(2)
         P=p+t-180;
     end
 elseif a<=a_s | a_s-180<a
     if p>=t        %------(3)
         P=p-t;
     elseif p<t     %------(4)
         P=p-t+180;
     end
 end
```

Comment: What is this meant to do?  (1)  It looks like the first `if` expression will never evaluate to true.  (2)  Since `a` is a vector, do you want all, or any of the elements to match the condition?  Or do you want to check each element individually?

Comment: ---------actual equations--------
 if a_s<a<=a_s-180,
         P=p+t     for p<=180-t,
         P=p+t-180 for p>180-t
 if a<=a_s or a_s-180<a,       
         P=p-t     for p>=t,    
         P=p-t+180 for p<t
% The two if's are connected

Answer (score 1):

Try the following substitutions:

Substitute this:

```
 if p<=180-t    %------(1)
     P=p+t;
 elseif p>180-t %------(2)
     P=p+t-180;
 end
```

for this:

```
P = p+t;
P(P<=180) = P(P<=180)-180;
```

and this:

```
 if p>=t        %------(3)
     P=p-t;
 elseif p<t     %------(4)
     P=p-t+180;
 end
```

for this:

```
P = p-t;
P(P<0) = P(P<0)+180;
```

as for the two ifs for `a_s` and `a` it's not clear if you want to execute the branch when `any()` condition is true or only if all of them are true (which is the default).  Remember that `a` is a vector, so `a<a_s` is a boolean vector.

Comment: % Thanks for the reply. But this also produced the 
     % same result which I used to get on my machine. 
     % Here I am trying to write the equations more
     % elegantly. 
     if a_s<a<=a_s-180
        P=p+t     for p<=180-t,
        P=p+t-180 for p>180-t
     elseif  a<=a_s | a_s-180<a       
        P=p-t     for p>=t,    
        P=p-t+180 for p<t

Comment: The problem may lie with the `if  a_s<a<=a_s-180` and `elseif` statements.  Try the logic using a scalar value in each parameter to find where it fails.

Comment: And remember that when you check `a_s < a` for a vector `a`, this checks TRUE only if all the elements of `a` are greater than `a_s`. If any one is FALSE then the following statements are not executed.

Comment: But for the case a_s<a, I have the elseif statement.

Comment: The code starts from first if, read condition (2) then goes to condition (4) directly. There are two subconditions for P after first if (1) & (2)and again two subconditions for P after elseif. (3) & (4).

Comment: Which may also not execute.  For ex:  `a = [-1 1]  and a_s = 0` if you evaluate: `if a_s < a ... do M ... elseif a < a_s ... do N`  will neither do M nor N.  In both cases the condition turns to be false.  Should you have an `else ... do Z ... end` then this will execute when the others are false.